# What does Override Method mean?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy for the first time and when I generate a new spider this blue symbol pops up. What does it mean? And most importantly, should I be worried about it?. I guess there's nothing wrong with it because I have only generated a new spider. Thanks in advance!

[image: The first symbol says: 'Overrides attribute in Spider'. The second says: 'Overrides method in Spider]

Comment: It means that the parrent class defines a method with the same name. So your subclass redefines the method for its instances.

Comment: If you intended to override the default action for your class, then you shouldn't be worried. It's just a warning in case you accidentally reused a method name without realizing it.